# Project multiple textures during a DynoTopo sculpt?

Tags: uv, sculpting, dynamic-topology

I've been messing with the UV Project modifier. This appears to require a UV map to be present for a mesh.  Unfortunately, sculpting with dynamic topology activated removes vertex data such as UV maps.

Is there some way to project (perhaps in world or generated space) one or more images onto a mesh during DynoTopo sculpting?  Optimally, I'd like to be able to project multiple images a la UV Project but I'll take what I can get.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using those images as guides to where to sculpt ,use multiple cameras and set up multiple 3d views.
with this setup you could sculpt-draw on a 3d view with the background image and see the changes on another 3d view.

use multiple cameras , each camera should load an image ,use a low opacity value and set it to display in front of everything.

[image]

you can also keyframe cameras to quickly switch between multiple angles, so that frame 1 is camera 1 and uses an image, frame 2 is another angle from another camera etc..

I don't think you can use more than one image at a time with this though.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is how I currently do this. I guess I'm not sure why UV Project requires a UV map. I'd be happy if I could just project in world coordinates. I'll experiment with spot lights to see if I can achieve it that way.